# How to Mix 2 list as Dictionary in Python with custom key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, list

### I have 2 List

#### 1. Contains `Keys`

#### 2. Contains `Keys+Values`

##### Now I have to make a Dictionary from it which will filter out the keys and insert all the values before the next key arrives in the list.

Example:

```
List 1: ['a','ef','ddw','b','rf','re','rt','c','dc']
List 2: ['a','b','c']

Dictionary that I want to create: {
'a':['ef','ddw'],
'b':['rf','re','rt'],
'c':['dc']
}
```

###### I am only familiar with `python` language and want solution for same in python only.

Comment: See [ask]. How did you try to solve this?

Comment: Yes i can share my code as well but not getting the result with my logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
result = {}
cur_key = None
for key in list_1:
    if key in list_2:
        result[key] = []
        cur_key = key
    else:
        result[cur_key].append(key)
```

Comment: Thanks! it got me right!